# Como Utilizar Variables en JSF

Tags: jsf, jpa, xhtml

Mi duda es como declara una variable para poder hacer un sub total, y después realizar un contador en `JSF`

Según investigue  se podría realizar esto:

```
<ui:param name="sub" value="#{item.canProductos * item.ideProducto.preProducto}" /> 

 <h:outputText value="#{sub}"/>
```

Pero no me genera ningún resultado, ni siquiera un error.

Despues de eso necesitaria sumar esa variable `sub` y generar un `total`
 algo asi;

```
<!--TOTAL DE LA COMPRA-->
<ui:param name="total" value="#{ total += sub}" /> 
<h:outputText  value="#{total}"/>
```

Se que no es correcto eso de `total += sub`   pero como podria hacerlo ?

Muchas gracias.

PDT: Tambien intente esto :

> (the namespace first)

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

> then

```
<c:set var="varName" value="#{complexModel.currencyAmount}" />
And then the calculated value will be accessible through #{varName}.
```

Pero no me reconoció la ruta en el proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al fin y al cabo se está haciendo uso de un `Managed Bean` para acceder a las variables, i.e. `item.canProductos * item.ideProducto.preProducto`

Por qué no dejar que el Managed Bean haga el cálculo, en vez de crear lógica en la vista ?

Algo así como:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductosBacking {

    List<Item> items;
    long totalSub;
    long subShow;

    public ProductosBacking() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item("Item a", 9, new IdeProducto(40)));
        items.add(new Item("Item b", 4, new IdeProducto(2)));
        items.add(new Item("Item c", 105, new IdeProducto(9)));
    }

    public long getSub(long canProductos, long preProducto) {
        long sub = canProductos * preProducto;

        totalSub += sub;
        System.out.printf("Sub %d \nTotalSub: %d", sub, totalSub);
        return sub;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public long getTotalSub() {
        return totalSub;
    }

    public void updateVal() {}
}
```

Y en el facelet:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{productosBacking.items}" var="item" border="1" cellpadding="20px" cellspacing="10">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Item Name</f:facet>
            #{item.nombre}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">CanProducto</f:facet>
            #{item.canProductos}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">PreProducto</f:facet>
            #{item.ideProducto.preProducto}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Sub</f:facet>
            #{productosBacking.getSub(item.canProductos, item.ideProducto.preProducto)}
    </h:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:form>
            Total Sub: <h:outputText value="#{productosBacking.totalSub}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Calcular Sub" action="#{productosBacking.updateVal()}" style="float: right; ">
                <f:ajax render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </f:facet>
</h:dataTable>
```